# Ubuntu project files and directories documentation

Tags: development

When you download some larger project, there is usually the documentation describing what is in individual files and directories and its purpose.

I can't find this information for the main (controlling) part of `Ubuntu` [project](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/).

Moreover I can't find some `readme` file in the project describing it. Does this officially exist? Could you post me a link? (This would be extremely difficult to answer it without a link).

I have also found [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28355/what-is-the-structure-of-an-ubuntu-repository) question but it's depricated and doesn't answer my question, so I asked rather this question (I also consulted it with a moderator of this portal yesterday).

Comment: Its kinda hard to understand what you are looking for here, are you expecting to understand the structure of an Ubuntu repository? If so the [2nd answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/28397/25863) in the last link you have in your question satisfies that.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Source_Code_Directory_Structure) is described the structure for Firefox project, something like this I'd like to have for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you want to know about Ubuntu itself and not the repositories.

An installation of Ubuntu uses the most common directory structure for Linux-based operating systems, the *Filesystem Hierarchy Standard*. Its official documentation can be found in:

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

If you don't need much more than basic information, though, the Wikipedia article on FHS might be a quicker introduction:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

If instead of an installation you are talking about source code, Ubuntu has no such thing as a single directory structure. This is because Ubuntu is a huge, modular collection of several different softwares, each one with its own structure.

In other words, you can't find what you are looking for unless you are more specific: "directory structure of the kernel", "directory structure of the file manager", "directory structure of the music player", "directory structure of the web browser", and so on.

Comment: I meant Ubuntu project files and directories.

Comment: The document looks good. I'm looking for similar description of files and directories but for the Ubuntu project.

Comment: So you are talking about source code? I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, source code. Every project has a directory structure. The question is, if it has documentation (decription of what is in directories devoted to modules etc.) like [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Source_Code_Directory_Structure) has. It can be in some `readme` file (format plays no role).

Comment: Did you read the paragraphs I added? If you are talking about source code, you need to be more specific... Perhaps edit your question mentioning which part of Ubuntu you're interested in, so people can point you to the specific project page.

Comment: OK, I will add it to the question.